# How to use Horizontal ScrollView With one Fixed layout positioned at center?

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I wanna implement the horizontal layout with fixed layout that is positioned at center. But the problem is that when i kept the layout at the center the horizontal scrollview child layout will be overlap by the fixed layout that i have kept on center. How to separate the space on horizontal scroll view so that while scrolling the scrollview child will jump the the space that we have define and position at the right and left of the center layout. 
How can it be possible? Please Give some idea. Happy if you provide me code. Hope with positive response. 
[image: Horizontal ScrollView With one Fixed Layout]

Comment: You can make use of relative layout, keep imageview at left of parent - rest of the horizontal  scrollview to the right of imageview

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: It will hide the icon of horizontal scroll view which is position on center?

Comment: You need to create custom hosrizontal scrollview

Comment: No idea on customizing horizontal scrollview. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of FRAME layout, keep imageview gravity at center - rest of the horizontal scrollview as it is.

For reference check the below code

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I want to kept Image view at center. Problem occur while kept in center. Image View will hide the icon that i kept on horizontal ScrollView.

Comment: you can also make use of framelayout in that case, but you will have keep some space vacant in your horizontalscrollview. check the updated answer

Comment: The icon shown in horizontal scrollview is dynamic, there may be 3 4 5 6 7 8 and so on... how to maintain space on that case?